# How to call tpl from custom module and controller override

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I'm developing a custom module to redirect some users (if they are in specific groups) to a custom page (i.e. B2B customers redirected to /fobidden-b2b when trying to go to /addresses). Redirect is working fine but I need to customize the "my-account" template links because I prefer to remove directly menu items and not hide them via CSS.
In my module I've the MyAccountController override (in module_root/override/controllers/front/MyAccountController.php) but I can't load my tpl from inside custom module folder.

This is the MyAccountController override:

```
class MyAccountController extends MyAccountControllerCore
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        $module = Module::getInstanceByName('custom_module');
        parent::initContent();
        $module->checkCustomer();
        // $module->toBeBlocked <= is the array with not allowed controllers
        
        // Tried the following but error
        // $this->setTemplate('module:'.$module->name.'/views/templates/customer/my-account.tpl');

        // Tried the following but error
        // $this->setTemplate(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module->name.'/views/templates/customer/my-account.tpl');
    }
}
```

In my tpl I would read the allowed menu items and the disallowed (defining arrays) so using Smarty I could check and "print" only the allowed menu items.

I would like to have all in my module folder to simplify, without have to manually add files in "themes/[theme_name]/modules/custom_module/views/templates/..." folder

How can I do?

Comment: What error do you have? Could you also show the content of my-account.tpl?

Comment: At the moment the tpl is the same as the default but with an additional custom text. The error is "no template found".